# Why the getYear() of Java Date class returns a wrong value?

Tags: java, date

I am working on a Java application and I have some problem trying to obtain the value of the year from a **Date** object.

So basically I have the following situation:

Basically into my code I have:

```
Date datePrimoVersamento = sdf.parse(mappaQuote.get(1).getDatariferimentoprezzo());
Date dateMovimentoFinale = sdf.parse(mappaQuote.get(0).getDatariferimentoprezzo());

System.out.println("datePrimoVersamento: " + datePrimoVersamento + " year: " + datePrimoVersamento.getYear());
System.out.println("dateMovimentoFinale: " + " year: " + dateMovimentoFinale.getYear());
```

The output is:

```
datePrimoVersamento: Fri Nov 27 00:00:00 CET 2015 year: 115
dateMovimentoFinale: Mon Oct 31 00:00:00 CET 2016 year: 116
```

As you can see the year of the 2 dates are **2015** an **2016** but the **getYear()** method returns to me **115** and **116**.

Why? How is it possible? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why don't you read the Javadoc of getYear()? Hint - it returns `the year represented by this date, minus 1900`

Comment: You should not use it, because it is deprecated. `Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900.`

Comment: I think this is the fourth time in two weeks that I read this question.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Javadoc:

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900.
>   Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

So: 2016 - 1900 = 116 and 2015 - 1900 = 115.

You should try this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(datePrimoVersamento );
System.out.println("datePrimoVersamento's Year: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
cal.setTime(dateMovimentoFinale );
System.out.println("dateMovimentoFinale's Year: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getFullYear()`. `getYear()` simply returns the number of years since 1900.

Answer (score 1):

As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900.

Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

Returns: the year represented by this date, minus 1900.
Please use Calender class

Answer (score 0):

The year value returned from getYear() is the amount of years passed since 1900.